# Splitting AC voltage based on phase

Tags: voltage, analog, ac, oscillator, single-phase

Is it possible to separate the positive and negative portions of an AC voltage wave into two separate lines, where one line has the positive voltage portion (and is neutral when the source is negative), and another has the negative voltage portion (and is neutral when the source is positive)?

Here's a diagram to try to clear up any misunderstandings:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5QkIs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So if VMI's output looked like this:

[image: VMI]

VM+ and VM- would look like the following:

[image: VM+][image: VM-]

If it matters, this is purely hypothetical; I don't plan on trying to build said circuit anytime soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a *Half-Wave Rectifier* is what you mean.
[image]

Comment: I don't think so. Wouldn't both of the AC outputs have the same signal (equivalent to what VM+ should be)?

Comment: sorry, that's fixed now

Comment: The two outputs shouldn't be marked AC. They are really unfiltered DC with respect to ground.

Comment: @CharlesCowie technically, it's still AC (alternates between gnd and +, or between gnd and -). If it helps, place an "AC coupling capacitor" on each output line...the circuit still works, only now the output voltage becomes a 1/2 voltage (and somewhat distorted) copy of the input waveform. The basic premise of pretty much all RF engineering revolves around that property of "pulsed dc"/"unfiltered dc", allowing us to make clean ac waveforms from single-ended DC inputs.

Comment: Yes, but the asker seemed to be heading in the direction making a dual DC supply. However, the fact that the asker accepted the answer is probably all that matters.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB: Technically, it's not AC, its  what's called "Pulsating DC".  AC, or Alternating Current, being a signal which swings above and below zero volts.  That signal would appear on the input on the "AC" line and would swing above and below GND. The output signals which you have mislabeled "AC" are actually pulsating DC signals with the signal from the cathode of the upper diode swinging positive WRT GND and the signal from the anode of the lower diode swinging negative WRT GND.  Furthermore, all of your references to RF are disingenuous, irrelevant, and off topic.